# Layout in ScrollView is updated incorrectly when soft keyboard shows/hides

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, soft-keyboard

I have a simple layout which consists of Entry and the Button. The goal is to place Button at the bottom and the Entry in the center of the remaining space. Everything works at start. Here are layout and screenshot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             x:Class="ParentAdda.Pages.Test">
    <ScrollView x:Name="Qq" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout x:Name="Ww" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <BoxView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="0" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" />
            <Entry
                FontSize="Medium"
                Placeholder="+111111111"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Keyboard="Telephone" />
            <BoxView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="0" BackgroundColor="Coral" />
            <Button Text="Update" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    BorderRadius="20"
                    BackgroundColor="Lime"
                    TextColor="White"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    FontAttributes="Bold" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

I am also setting WindowSoftInputMode to resize in Android project (in the code, taking into account the bug in Xamarin.Forms when the tag is reset to Pan when set in manifest when using `FormsAppCompatActivity`)

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        //https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39765
        App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
        //https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39765
        //Remove the status bar underlay in API 21+
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = 0;
            var statusBarHeightInfo = typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("_statusBarHeight", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            statusBarHeightInfo?.SetValue(this, 0);
            Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
        }
    }
```

When Entry gains focus, the page is not resized (though I can scroll to the very bottom when soft keyboard is visible)

[image]

When soft keyboard hides the content is resized incorrectly, and occupies just part of the screen.[image]

It looks like the layout process is performed based on bounds before soft keyboard becomes visible/invisible. However, it seems that all `Bounds` properties (of the Page, ScrollView and StackLayout) as well as `ContentSize` property of ScrollView has correct numeric values (i traced them in button clicked handler). I tried to call `ForceLayout()` on different elements in same button clicked handler without luck.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I do think it's how `FillAndExpand` of `VerticalOptions` is designed, it is for 
element layout when there is excess space available along the Y axis from the parent layout. If multiple children of a layout are set to expand, the extra space is distributed proportionally.

Since you don't have any fixed size, when the keyboard is disappearing, the layout is resized, I guess `FillAndExpand` will first measure how many extra space along the axis and then distributes the space for the children.

A very simple workaround to solve your issue is to give a fixed size to your `StackLayout`, but you said

> The goal is to place Button at the bottom and the Entry in the center of the remaining space.

If you want to keep the original size here, you can set the height to `StackLayout` when it is appearing, means override the `OnAppearing()` method in code behind, for example:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Ww.HeightRequest = Ww.Height;
}
```